# MAMP Pro and PDO-dblib

Tags: pdo, mamp, mamp-pro

For some days I've been using MAMP Pro 3.07 from http://www.mamp.info. 
Great tool and all works fine.
But now I have the problem, that for a new project I need to connect to MSSQL.

I searched for a howto the last 3 hours in www, but can´t find a working answer or am I to stupid?

Is there a possibility to install "PDO-dblib" on MAMP on OSX Yosemite?

Or can somebody explain me how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP website](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php):

> PDO_DBLIB: This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.

I [see](https://www.mamp.info/en/) MAMP allows you to use different versions of PHP, so if you choose php 5.1.6 it may work. There is also a [comment](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php#118093) there from a guy who wrote its own class for this purpose. I am adding you also the `pecl` [repository](https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_DBLIB) for this `PDODblib`.

Apart of this I am recommending you to use the latest version of PHP and do not rely on maintained extensions. PDO, which comes now by default with PHP, allows you to connect to MSSQL databases and you can find documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) and [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

Comment: Using MAMP Pro, latest version, PDO by default doesn't support mssql extension. MAMP's PHPInfo() shows only mysql, pgsql, and sqlite.